# Call a dynamic function in php

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way to call dynamic functions in php. For an example lets guess I have a variable like below.

```
$myVar = 'my_test_function';
```

And I have a function named **myTestFunction()**. Is there a way to call the mentioned function using the $myVar variable's value? How to structure that variable as myTestFunction and call the mentioned function using that variable

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the following:

```
lcfirst(str_replace('_', '', ucwords($myVar, '_')))();
```

Comment: But the names are different. I should remove the underscores and capitalize the next letter. How should I do that?

Comment: I've edited the code to a one liner.

Answer (score 2):

convert your string to function name first:

```
$myVar = 'my_test_function';
echo $myVar = str_replace('_', '', ucwords($myVar, '_')); //output myTestFunction
$myVar();
```

Comment: As function names are case insensitive, you could just replace the underscores and be done with it.

Comment: @Yoshi yes you are right, but its good practice to have strict code techniques for future use.

Comment: True, but I don't see the relevance here. It just adds overhead on the processing side, and if the stored name is never used (e.g. logging) it serves no real purpose.